# Sending json to webservice, receiving null. - Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I'm new to this. The web service to read json from the server works, however when I create a new record via json in Android, it sends, but I receive null.

**Code**:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.42.194/app/web/app.php/android/buscar");
post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
try {
    JSONStringer dato = new JSONStringer().object().key("cadena").value("valor").endObject();
    StringEntity entidad = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
    post.setEntity(entidad);
    HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(post);
    String obtiene = EntityUtils.toString(respuesta.getEntity());
    JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(obtiene);
    String mensaje = object2.getString("cod");
    Log.e("LOG", mensaje.toString());
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enviado "+ mensaje);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enviar " + query.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: What happens when your formulate a post to the endpoint manually? Does it work?  What is the expected response?

Comment: this HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(post); return code 200, not null but this line: String obtiene = EntityUtils.toString(respuesta.getEntity());return null of the server, i use restclient-ui-3.1 to try the request and works, i can read json from server, but i cant send json to the server

Comment: What I am triyng to get at is whether it is problem with server of client.  When you manually build a post with JSON using restclient and POST it to the server, does it work?

Comment: it works, the error is in the code android

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header on the StringEntity and not the post itself, also JSON is by default UTF-8 so it is not needed

```
HttpClient cliente = new DefaultHttpClient();
JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();
try {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.42.194/app/web/app.php/android/buscar");
    dato.put("cadena", "valor");
    StringEntity entidad = new StringEntity(dato.toString());  
    entidad.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    post.setEntity(entidad);
    HttpResponse respuesta = cliente.execute(post);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enviar " + query.getText());
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```